# Filter raster by taking the max of a Gaussian filter

Tags: raster, r, filter, terra

I have a raster which I applied a Gaussian filter. By "default", the Gaussian filter, takes the mean within the kernel. How can I take the max, instead of the mean, within the kernel?

Here is how I applied the Gaussian filter:

```
library(terra)

wd = "test/"

dem = rast(paste0(wd, "dem.tif")) # my original raster

gf <- focalMat(dem, 0.5*30, "Gauss")
r_gf <- focal(dem, w = gf, na.rm = TRUE)
```

The raster I am using:

```
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 487, 538, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 29.97561, 29.97126  (x, y)
extent      : 330330.3, 346457.2, 4451378, 4465974  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : GGRS87 / Greek Grid (EPSG:2100) 
source      : dem.tif 
name        :       dem 
min value   :  144.7688 
max value   : 2169.7751
```

I am using `R` 4.3.1 and `RStudio` 2023.06.1 Build 524.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try setting the argument `fun="max"` inside the focal() function? See this section from the [terra docs](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/terra/terra.pdf).

[image]

Comment: I wasn't expecting it to be that easy.